# How to combine retry with sending DLQ in spring cloud stream kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring-cloud-stream-kafka, version 2.1.2.
And retry using the default RetryTemplate.

In the process of using, there is a situation that the monitor fails repeatedly and retries repeatedly.

In this case, the retry doesn't make much sense and can lead to other problems.

Therefore, is there any way to send it to DLQ if it still fails after retrying for a certain number of times, such as 10 times?

That's my first question.

In the document, set the configuration of DLQ as follows:

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true

So, what is the configuration of all topic like?

That's my second question.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're asking. The retries effectively imply that something will be retried based on your configuration until the final resolution and in your case the final resolution is DLQ. Sp what I am saying is that "send it to DLQ if it still fails after retrying for a certain number of times" should just work otherwise that would be a bug, so please clarify if something is not working. With regard to "what is the configuration of all topic like", I am also not sure what exactly you are asking, so pease clarify

Comment: I may have sent the wrong message, and I mistook the error redelivery for a retry.In fact, I would like to be able to send it to DLQ after a certain number of redeliveries.The current solution is to use spring-retry and still fail and send it to DLQ

Comment: Second, I hope to send all the themes to a unified DLQ, can this be done?